# VueJs Like and Dislike buttons with Vfor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button

how to make the buttons increase separately?, I have tried similar solutions but they increase the number in the like and dislike together at the same time,
and I have this message in the console:

> vue@next:1250 [Vue warn]: Property "counter" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
> at

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="comment--like--dislike--app">
        <div
          v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index"
          class="card mb-10 comment--item"
        >
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint
            deserunt, tempore accusamus iusto nobis dolore ratione itaque
            perferendis delectus? Nostrum corporis, quod voluptates quis
            consequuntur eveniet beatae dolor aperiam ad.
          </p>
          <div class="action--button--container text-right mt-10">
            <button v-on:click="increment(index)" v-bind:id="comments.id" class="btn-sm btn-success">
              Like ({{comments.counter}})
            </button>
            <button  v-on:click="increment(index)" v-bind:id="comments.id"  class="btn-sm btn-danger">
              Dislike ({{comments.counter}})
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is the Vue code:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            comments: [{
              id: 1,
              counter:0
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              counter:0
            },
          ],
          };
        },
        methods: {
          increment: function(index) {
            this.comments[index].counter++;
          },
        },
      }).mount(".container");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using `comments.counter` instead of `comment.counter` (the comment at the current index in the array `comments`).

Change your markup to look like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="comment--like--dislike--app">
        <div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="index" class="card mb-10 comment--item">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint
                deserunt, tempore accusamus iusto nobis dolore ratione itaque
                perferendis delectus? Nostrum corporis, quod voluptates quis
                consequuntur eveniet beatae dolor aperiam ad.
            </p>
            <div class="action--button--container text-right mt-10">
                <button v-on:click="increment(index)" v-bind:id="comment.id" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                    Like ({{comment.counter}})
                </button>
                <button v-on:click="increment(index)" v-bind:id="comment.id" class="btn-sm btn-danger">
                    Dislike ({{comment.counter}})
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, as ashwin bande pointed out in the comments, you have a logic issue as well. You are using `increment(index)` for both your like and dislike buttons.

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is this:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      comments: [{
          id: 1,
          counter: {
            likes: 0,
            dislikes: 0
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          counter: {
            likes: 0,
            dislikes: 0
          }
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment(index) {
      this.comments[index].counter.likes++;
    },
    decrement(index) {
      this.comments[index].counter.dislikes++;
    },
  },
}).mount(".container");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="comment--like--dislike--app">
    <div
      v-for="(comment, index) in comments"
      :key="index"
      class="card mb-10 comment--item"
    >
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint 
        deserunt, tempore accusamus iusto nobis dolore ratione itaque 
        perferendis delectus? Nostrum corporis, quod voluptates quis 
        consequuntur eveniet beatae dolor aperiam ad.
      </p>
      <div class="action--button--container text-right mt-10">
        <button
          @click="increment(index)" 
          :id="comment.id"
          class="btn-sm btn-success"
        >
          Like ({{comment.counter.likes}})
        </button>
        
        <button
          @click="decrement(index)"
          :id="comment.id"
          class="btn-sm btn-danger"
        >
          Dislike ({{comment.counter.dislikes}})
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but the like and dislike button still synced and giving the same number when you click one of them

Comment: you are using same `increment(index)` for both like and dislike. is that the issue ?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I must have missed that part of the question initially. I've updated the answer to address that.

Comment: thanks for your solutions, actually it worked, and clearly, I have a problem with the data structure, do you have in your mind any courses that might help? or does the CS50 is enough?

Comment: I'd recommend looking up data structures on youtube. Here's a good video to start off with: https://youtu.be/RBSGKlAvoiM